# How to move partial text from one cell to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, code

I have a dilemma I am hoping someone might be able to help me with!
I have exported a PDF file into excel that has a lot of information that populates into one cell. I need to split this information into separate cells, but all the information has different spacing. Here is an example:

```
John Smith 1234 Main St
Charlie Motto 6548 Teflon Ave
Shannon Guesswho 12W546 Spoon Dr
```

So, I need to put the names in one cell and the addresses (Preferably numeric and street separate).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Copy/paste? My experience of PDF extractions is that they are often messy and there is no easy way to deal with them

Comment: How do you want to split the name and address?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Copy from PDF
2. Paste in text file (I use Notepad)
3. Copy from text file
4. Paste in excel
5. Select "Use Text Import Wizard…" in the paste icon
6. Select Next 3 times and see if the results are correct

You can manage the wizard to request best results

Comment: I don’t see ‘‘Use Text Import Wizard…’’ in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2013:

1. Copy text (from PDF file).
2. Click in the spreadsheet in the upper left corner
   of where you want the data to go.
3. Paste. 
   You may want to do “Paste”  → ”Match Destination Formatting (M)”.

   [image]

   Ensure that the left column (Column `A`) is selected.
4. Select “Data”  → “Data Tools”  → “Text to Columns”.

   [image]
5. “Step 1 of 3” – Select “Delimited”
   (because your strings are delimited by spaces, and do not have a fixed width). 
   Click <kbd>Next ></kbd>.

   [image]
6. “Step 2 of 3” – Select the appropriate delimiter. 
   In your case, it looks like it is space. 
   Click <kbd>Next ></kbd>.

   [image]
7. “Step 3 of 3” – Optionally, assign a data format to each column. 
   I usually skip this step. 
   Click <kbd>Finish</kbd>. 
   You’ll get something like this:

   [image]
8. If you want street name and street type together,

   - Enter `=D1 & " " & E1` into cell `F1`.
   - Drag/fill down:

   [image]

   - Select Column `F`.
   - Copy it, and paste values over Column `D`.
   - Clear Columns `E` and `F`.
9. Combine Column `A` (first name) and Column `B` (last name) similarly.